# VirtualHost not redirecting

Tags: node.js, apache, redirect, port, virtualhost

I am trying to redirect `http://eamondev.com:3000` to `https://omniatm.eamondev.com` with a `VirtualHost`. I am using `node` to serve a site to `http://eamondev.com:3000`. I am using `vhost` with node like this:

```
app.use(vhost('omniatm.eamondev.com', express.static('/')));
```

I have never used `vhost` and it took me a while to figure this out without having to split up all my code like I was working with more than one site (when I am not), so I'm not sure if it is exactly how it should be for an Apache redirect to work.

In my `apache` `conf` file I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName omniatm.eamondev.com
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

I am also using WHM on a VPS, I'm not sure if this is relevant or not, but the `ServerName` (with protocol, what I type into the browser) needs to be `https://omniatm.eamondev.com`.

I cannot serve `node` on port `80` of my server (and then redirect to subdomain)  because my main site (http://eamondev.com) is running on port `80`.

I have referenced most of the stackoverflow questions about this and nothing has worked. I should mention (although I'm not sure exactly how it is relevant, I just saw it in a stackoverflow question I looked at), my hosting support (`bluehost`) used `WHM` to set things up with a wildcard `ssl` certificate to make the `omniatm.eamondev.com` subdomain `https`.

How do I redirect http://eamondev.com:3000 to https://omniatm.eamondev.com using `apache` (or `vhost`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxy passing as given in the question will not do any redirects instead it will retain the URL as such and proxy the content from elsewhere. In Apache configuration, we have an option to do redirects, in the bellow sample, we are checking for the host and based on it issuing an redirect to the desired URL

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName omniatm.eamondev.com
    Redirect / https://omniatm.eamondev.com
    <If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'eamondev.com:3000'">
     Redirect "^/?(.*)"  "https://omniatm.eamondev.com/$1"
   </If>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please add some details description, so that anyone can understand your answer at a glance.

Comment: thanks @jeevan, tied up at the moment with another project, i will try this soon and award points if it works